# Four simultaneous equations

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

General form of the function:
$$y=d\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{ax+b}2\right)+c$$
I want the function to pass three points, $(0,0)$, $\left(\frac{t}2,\frac{g}2\right)$ and $(t,g)$, and I want the function to have a slope of $r$ at the $\left(\frac{t}2,\frac{g}2\right)$ point.

I want to rewrite the function above, but now expressed in $t$, $g$ and $r$.

Equation 1:
$$y(0)=0$$
$$0=d\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{b}2\right)+c$$
$$-c=d\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{b}2\right)$$
Equation 2:
$$\left(\frac{g}2\right)=d\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{at+2b}4\right)+c$$
Equation 3:
$$g=d\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{at+b}2\right)+c$$
Equation 4:
$$r=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$r=\frac{ad}{\sqrt{(ax+b)^2+4}}$$

Any comments will be greatly appreciated. Even stopping by is greatly appreciated!